# What is the difference between references and normal variable handles in C++?

Tags: c++

If C++, if I write:

```
int i = 0;
int& r = i;
```

then are `i` and `r` exactly equivalent?

Answer (score 5):

That means that r is another name for i. They will both refer to the same variable. This means that if you write (after your code):

```
r = 5;
```

then `i` will be 5.

Comment: I could never understand "just another name for an object". Whenever I pass the parameter by reference, I pass "another name"? Not at all! const reference is a constant another name? It is not! Will sizeof(reference) be always equal to sizeof(object)? (well... not sure myself...) I understand reference as a constant pointer, that is dereferenced automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The *Reference* is an *alias* of an object. i.e  alternate name of an object. Read this article for more information - http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html

Answer (score 3):

References are slightly different, but for most intents and purposes it is used identically once it has been declared.

There is slightly different behavior from a reference, let me try to explain.

In your example 'i' represents a piece of memory.  'i' owns that piece of memory -- the compiler reserves it when 'i' is declared, and it is no longer valid (and in the case of a class it is destroyed) when 'i' goes out of scope.

However 'r' does not own it's own piece of memory, it represents the same piece of memory as 'i'.  No memory is reserved for it when it is declared, and when it goes out of scope it does not cause the memory to be invalid, nor will it call the destructor if 'r' was a class.  If 'i' somehow goes out of scope and is destroyed while 'r' is not, 'r' will no longer represent a valid piece of memory.

For example:

```
class foo
{
public:
  int& r;
  foo(int& i) : r(i) {};
}

void bar()
{
  foo* pFoo;

  if(true)
  {
    int i=0;
    pFoo = new foo(i);
  }

  pFoo->r=1; // r no longer refers to valid memory
}
```

This may seem contrived, but with an object factory pattern you could easily end up with something similar if you were careless.

I prefer to think of references as being most similar to pointers during creation and destruction, and most similar to a normal variable type during usage.

There are other minor gotchas with references, but IMO this is the big one.

Answer (score 2):

A reference is an alias for an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

Yep - a reference should be thought of as an **alias** for a variable, which is why you can't reassign them like you can reassign pointers (and also means that, even in the case of a non-optimizing compiler, you won't take up any additional storage space).

When used outside of function arguments, references are mostly useful to serve as shorthands for very->deeply->nested.structures->and.fields :)

Answer (score 1):

> C++ references differ from pointers in
>   several essential ways:
>
> - It is not possible to refer directly to a reference object
>     after it is defined; any occurrence of its name refers directly to the
>     object it references.
> - Once a reference is    created, it cannot be later made to    reference
>     another object; it cannot be reseated. This is often done with pointers.
> - References cannot be null, whereas pointers can; every reference 
>     refers to some object, although it may or may not be valid.
> - References cannot be uninitialized. Because it is impossible to reinitialize a
>     reference, they must be initialized as soon as they are created. In particular, local and global variables must be initialized where they are defined, and references which are data members of class instances must be initialized in the initializer list of the class's constructor.

From [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).

Comment: But how do they differ from "normal" variable handles?  For example how is the r in my example different from the i?  Neither of these are pointers.  Pointers are not involved.

Comment: This actually answers a different question

Comment: answering the wrong question - questions is about references and stack allocated variables - not references and pointers

Comment: +1 for the answer, -1 for mentioning pointers, making the (wrong) impression that pointers and references are somehow related.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax int &r=i; creates another name i.e. r for variable i.hence we say that r is reference to i.if you access value of r,then r=0.**Remember Reference is moreover a direct connection as its just another name for same memory location.**

Answer (score 0):

You are writing definitions here, with initializations. That means that you're refering to code like this:

```
void foo() {
    int i = 0;
    int& r = i;
}
```

but not

```
class bar {
    int m_i;
    int& m_r;
    bar() : i(0), r(i) { }
};
```

The distinction matters. For instance, you can talk of the effects that m_i and m_r have on `sizeof(bar)` but there's no equivalent `sizeof(foo)`.

Now, when it comes to using `i` and `r`, you can distinguish a few different situations:

- Reading, i.e. `int anotherInt = r;`
- Writing, i.e. `r = 5`
- Passing to a function taking an `int`, i.e. `void baz(int); baz(r);`
- Passing to a function taking an `int&`, i.e. `void baz(int&); baz(r);`
- Template argument deduction, i.e. `template<typename T> void baz(T); baz(r);`
- As the argument of `sizeof`, i.e. `sizeof(r)`

In these cases, they're identical. But there is one very important distinction:

```
std::string s = std::string("hello");
std::string const& cr = std::string("world");
```

The reference extends the lifetime of the temporary it's bound to, but the first line makes its a copy.

Comment: Could you please post some standard or other literature references about references extending lifetime?

Comment: I think we had the discussion before :) The second one using the const reference is free to make a copy too. But the really important thing is that the second *will keep the original type when it copies*, that is, *it does not slice off* a derived part. Used in such useful libraries like ScopeGuard.