# C++ Exact difference between having myMethod(Thing& a) or myMethod(Thing a)?

Tags: c++

What is the exact difference between having myMethod(Thing& a) or myMethod(Thing a)? Because later you still ned to use &a if you want the address of the object.. I'm not sure when to use what..

Comment: The same question also arises for the return type..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409775/what-is-the-difference-between-references-and-normal-variable-handles-in-c

Comment: Have you considered reading a book on C++ before posting this question?

Comment: Thx for the kind answers for my n00bish question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three differences:

1. With a reference, you have a "shared" instance.  So if you modify `a` you change the original and vice versa.
2. Performance.  With `Thing a` you invoke the copy constructor.  If the copy constructor has to do a lot of things, that could affect how fast the code runs.
3. A reference is guaranteed to work.  If the class has a private copy constructor, you will not be able to do `Thing a` but you can always do `Thing &a`.

Finally, if you don't intend for the caller to be able to change the underlying object, you should probably pass by const reference (`const Thing &a`)

Answer (score 4):

In the first case you are just passing a *reference* to a single object, in the second case you are passing a copy of the object.

Comment: So if it makes a copy.. which constructor does it use then? Do I need to define a copy constructor?

Comment: You need to define a copy constructor if you're not satisfied with what the default copy constructor does. Same question I asked above arises...

Comment: A copy constructor is generated by default if you don't provide one and if you don't have a reference as member of the class. Search for infos about the default class member function called "the big four".

Comment: Copy constructor (as also Constructor and Destructor) is generated automatically if not specified explicitly. Note than by default the copy constructor makes a shallow copy (not deep copy), so your allocated data pointers are just copied as pointers and actual data isn't copied.

Comment: If you don't define your own copy constructor then the compiler will use an implicit copy constructor, which will of course only perform a shallow copy.

Comment: Yep, but after Klaim's response I thought something like "damn it, I don't know who is the fourth one" :)

Answer (score 0):

The second one creates a reference to the object, so these two bits of code are identical:

```
void addOne(int &a){
    a++;
}

void addOne(int *a){
    (*a)++;
}
```

The difference between with and without the & is that without it, your variable will be copied (and anything you do with it inside the function will be ignored), and with an &, anything you do to the variable inside the function will apply outside of the function as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about the precedence, but I added your suggestion.

Comment: Not exactly. `*a` can be `null` in the second instance, which will cause it to crash.

Comment: You could still pass `*((int*)NULL)` as the argument and get the same behavior (although, it'll crash before the function starts I think, but it's roughly the same behavior, just harder to do).