# What does int &f = d mean

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [References in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502687/references-in-c)
>   [What does int & mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629317/what-does-int-mean)

I am having difficulty understanding the statement `int &f = d` in the following code. I would appreciate it if someone could clear this up

```
int main()
{ 
   int d = 13 ;
   int &f = d ;
   std::cout << f;
}
```

Edit : I am familiar with the concept of references sorry I didnt give enough background.
I know that if i do something like this

```
int a = 12
std::cout << &a //this gives the address of a and not the content of the address which is 12
```

Now my issue with  `int &f = d`  
The problem to me is
f seems to require an address whereas d is giving it a value not an address.

Comment: If you have difficulty understanding it, it's time to spend some quality time with your favourite C++ text book (see the FAQ if you don't have one) or course notes.

Comment: instead of copying the answer, just see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409775/what-is-the-difference-between-references-and-normal-variable-handles-in-c

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Hmm.. the question isn't "could someone please explain the concept of references in C++", but rather, "what is this piece of syntax". :-( I think that qualifies for "does not show any research effort". (And by the way, who would *upvote* this?!)

Comment: Firstly, it's much clearer as `int& f = d;`. Secondly, what happened to your C++ book? Dog ate it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you can use either int& f or int &f. Wish I had a dog

Comment: @KeithNicholas just updated my question

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Symbol `&` in that declaration has absolutely nothing to do with "address of" operator and addresses in general. So, stop making guesses based on "what it looks like" to you and stop comparing it to `&` operator. It is meaningless. Read your favorite C++ book's chapter on references. Your edit that states that you are "familiar with the concept of references" shows that you are actually *not* familiar with that concept. You must be thinking about pointers. Pointers and references are different things in C++.

Comment: @AndreyT What does the reference to operator "&" return ? I believe it returns an address right. Jeez.. talk about being rude

Comment: @Rajeshwar: "...the reference to operator `&`..." - I don't know what you mean by this.

Comment: The only confusion I am having with this statement is that int &f should be given a pointer value instead its getting a non-pointer

Comment: @Rajeshwar: **No.** I don't know where you get this. `int *f` would need a pointer value as an initializer. Meanwhile, `int &f` is a completely different thing, which needs an `int` Lvalue as an initializer. Do you see the difference between `int *f` and `int &f`? The first is a pointer. The second is a reference.

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Yes, I'm quite aware that either is valid. But one is [clearer](http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/) than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I could write, and write, but better answer is here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C++)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29)

In general, in C++ it is something like a pointer. `f` is used as something that refers to what `d` is.